# Convert json to xml and remove empty strings

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js, parsing

I convert a json file to xml file and in my json file I have :

```
"settingsData": { 
    "settingsname": "",
    "username": "Dave",
    "password": "",
    "domain": "Benji",
}
```

My output is:

```
 <data name="settingsname" value=""/>
 <data name="username" value="Dave"/>
 <data name="password" value=""/>
 <data name="domain" value="Benji"/>
```

Here is my function :

```
var settings = [];

function extractData(data, settingsData){
    settings.push({
        name: 'settingsname',
        value: data.settingsname
    });
    settings.push({
        name: 'username',
        value: data.username
    });
    settings.push({
        name: 'password',
        value: data.password
    }); 
    settings.push({
        name: 'domain',
        value: data.domain
    }); 
    return settings;
}
```

The output needs to be :

```
<data name="username" value="Dave"/>
<data name="domain" value="Benji"/>
```

My Question is how can I remove the empty strings or how can I check if it is an empty string then do not add it to the array?

I used something like the following if statement, but it didn’t work :

```
 if (settingsData.settingsname !== ""){
    settings.push({
        name: 'settingsname',
        value: data.settingsname
    });
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over the array and check if the property exists:

```
var settingsData = {
    settingsname: '',
    username: 'Dave',
    password: '',
    domain: 'Benji'
};

function extractData(data, settingsData) {
    var settings = [];
    for (var key in settingsData ) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && settingsData[key].length > 0) {
           settings.push({name: key, value: data[key]});
       }
    }
    return settings;
}
```

Comment: Made a couple of edits to the code - I'm assuming you're passing `data` in from somewhere else, and so you need to iterate over keys in `settingsData`, but then check to make sure that key's value exists in `data`.

Comment: Normally I'd be more than happy to up vote your answer - but in this case, there was significant enough difference between what I was constructing vs. what your answer contains (and what the OP needed as an answer). Indeed, had I left it just made a direct copy that would be one thing, but I didn't. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyedzp92/)

```
var settingsData = {

    settingsname: '',
    username: 'Dave',
    password: '',
    domain: 'Benji'
};

function extractData(){

    var arr = [];

    for (var key in settingsData ) {
       if (settingsData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           if (settingsData[key]) arr.push(settingsData[key]);
       }
    }

    console.log(arr);
}

extractData(); // ["Dave", "Benji"]
```